# No pop-up showing up on Safari. Using interactive SVG

Tags: debugging, svg, safari, popup

I made an Interactive Workflow using SVG. Made this out of Adobe XD and transformed it to a working workflow where each button opens a pop-up modal and showing a video (like a lightbox).

*The problem I encounter is that the buttons don't work using Safari. Using Google Chrome or Firefox does work. What can I do to make this work for Safari as well?*

You can see an example of the interactive workflow via Fiddle.

To reproduce the problem you should open the link in Safari. If you want to see how it should work you should use Chrome or Firefox

**-- EDIT 25-03-19 --**

Thanks for the help but the answers did not work. Xlink:herf is kinda old and doesn't work for Safari. Maybe it does for regular links but i couldn't make my modal pop-up work.

I found a working example for the problem i was facing at http://jsbin.com/lajilacajumu/1/edit?html,css,output

Also made a preview with the information i saw in the example.

```css
.hoverable-rect {
  cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Bootstrap Bug Report</title>

<!-- Bootstrap's CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
    
<!-- the different buttons comes here -->
    <div class="container">
<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
<g class="hoverable-rect" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#modal1" id="g3223" id="prime-ppd" transform="translate(175.776 781.062)">
      <g id="prime-elements">
        <rect id="prime-bg" width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0" fill="#0094db"/>
        <text id="PRIME" transform="translate(4.65 26.098)" fill="#fff" font-size="11" font-family="HelveticaNeue-Medium, Helvetica Neue" font-weight="500" letter-spacing="-0.002em"><tspan x="0" y="0">PRIME</tspan></text>
      </g>
    </g>

</svg>

<!-- all different modals comes here -->
<div class="modal fade overlay" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/303329059?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap's JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - a cut-down example that demonstrates the problem.  Linking to your real site is discouraged because eventually you will likely fix that page and then this question and answer may become useless to future readers.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the tip. I reproduced the site to a Fiddle account. U can see the working example at https://jsfiddle.net/LeMans/szo5hqyp/14/. It still works on Firefox and Google Chrome but while using Safari i won't be able to click any of the buttons. So to reproduce the problem u should probably use Safari for this.

Comment: Updated Link Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/LeMans/szo5hqyp/16/

Comment: All we needed to see was one button. Not the whole mage.  That's what we mean by "minimal"  :)

Comment: i see and obvious too! Made a edit above with a working fiddle link.

Comment: Made it work, please see the code in my edited post

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<a href="whatever">
```

try

```
<a xlink:href="whatever">
```

SVG `<a>` elements are not the same as HTML `<a>` elements.  In the SVG version you link using `xlink:href`.

This requirement for the `xlink:` prefix has been dropped in SVG 2.  But not all browsers have implemented that yet.

Comment: I have read the article on CSS tricks. I tried it before and it did not seem to work on safari as well. For Google Chrome and Firefox there is no problem for opening the modal

Comment: Made it work, please see the code in my edited post